# Using apply to write to a global Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to create a new dataframe that has values added to it if a condition from another dataframe is met. Where if a column is not empty it would apply a function that would write the proceeding 90 rows to the new dataframe. However, I am having a host of errors when I am writing the current code, as I am having some confusion as to what value is being returned after applying the function.

I have written a code that uses a for loop, however it requires a significant time to execute. I was hoping to write the new code in just numpy and pandas.

```
df_regression = pd.DataFrame()

def func(x):
    global df_regression
    a = x.name
    b = x.name - 89

    df_writetoreg = df6_mod[b:a]
    df_regression = df_regression.append(df_writetoreg)
    return df_writetoreg    


df6_mod[pd.notnull(df6_mod['Characters1'])][['Characters1']].apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
```

****EDIT*****

Example:

DataFrame A

```
  Example      Value      Characters1
    A             10           NA
    A             20           NA
    A             30           1
    A             15           NA
    A             10           NA
    B             10           NA
    B             20           NA
    B             30           NA
    B             15           1
    B             10           NA
```

Therefore in this case, after applying the function, I want to create a dataframe B that will have all values preceding the "1" value found in the Characters1 column, where instead of 3 values you have 90.

DataFrame B

```
  Example      Value      Characters1
    A             10           NA
    A             20           NA
    A             30           1
    B             20           NA
    B             30           NA
    B             15           1
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you're asking.  Also, I cannot determine what you mean by looking at your code.  A better approach would be to provide sample data (better to provide the code to produce the dataframe) and show what the desired output should look like.  This way, we can iron out any vague descriptions of what's to be done with an example of what was expected.

Comment: Sorry about that, after reading it again, I can definitely see it being confusing.

So I current have Dataset A, and one of the columns of that Dataset contains a value. I want to call on a function that goes through that column and finds the non-NA values. Every time it detects a value in that column, it will apply the function that will slice the last 80 rows proceeding that row to a new dataframe (Datafame B for example). And the idea is to build a new dataframe that only has 80 rows for each of the non-NA values found in DataFrame A.

Comment: Let me know if you need more info, I dont know if I could provide you with the exact data, but I can reconstruct an example in an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is slightly unclear but here is what I think you need:

```
In[1] import pandas as pd
      df = pd.DataFrame({"Example": ["A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"], 
"Value": [10,20,30,15,10,10,20,30,15,10], "Characters1": [np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1, np.nan]})

In[2] df[df.Characters1.bfill(limit=2) == 1] # Replace limit=2 with 99 for your case
Out[2]: 
   Characters1 Example  Value
0          NaN       A     10
1          NaN       A     20
2          1.0       A     30
6          NaN       B     20
7          NaN       B     30
8          1.0       B     15
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this should work. And sorry about the vagueness, will make sure next question is very clear. Thanks again!